# Honoree Information - notify another person

Tags: civicontribute, honoree

I have a use-case for the Honoree section and I am unsure of whether it can be accomplished with the default functionality.

We'd like to add additional fields to the "Honoree Individual" profile to allow the donor to enter the name of someone to notify regarding the donation. (For example, if the donation is in memory of someone, they may wish a notification be sent to a certain living relative.) It's easy enough to add address fields to the profile:

[image: Honoree Information profile with additional fields]

However, this doesn't allow entry of the name of the contact to be notified, and I believe it attaches the address to the honoree. Is there a way to do what we want in the core contribution page, or should I set up a Webform with multiple contacts for this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it without doing some custom work.  The profile is going to create one contact for the honoree, and unfortunately, that's that.  One approach is to have a custom field for the information of who to notify, and then have a report of folks where that's set.  A staff member (who would presumably need to mail things anyway) could check that report and set up a new contact manually.

We have a client who wanted something like this, including automatically sending an email to the other person.  We built a custom extension to do it, and it might be a good starting point for abstracting it into an extension for others.

Comment: Is your extension 'shareable'?

Comment: Happy to share; Tyrell did the work and can put it up on GitHub when he gets a minute to clean things out.

Comment: Great -- will you post the link here when it goes up?

Comment: See https://github.com/aghstrategies/com.aghstrategies.softcreditnotify and https://github.com/aghstrategies/com.aghstrategies.softcreditacknowledge  Neither have been in active use for a couple of years, so I can't vouch for their compatibility with anything.

Answer (score 1):

A drupal webform can certainly accomplish what you're requesting. Set up:

- Contact 1: Contributor
- Contact 2: Honoree
- Contact 3: Notification recipient

It has the added benefit of being able to create relationships between these three contacts if you wish.